# How to extract two tuples from a single row in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, iterator, list-comprehension

I am trying to accomplish a rather simple task: I am reading in a csv file which contains an ID in column 0 and two texts associated with that ID in columns 2 and 3. I now want to form a list containing tuples of (ID, Text). Somehow, however, I cannot get this into a single list comprehension. Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv

with open(filename) as csvfile:

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)

    rows = [(row[0], row[2]) for row in reader]     
    rows.extend([(row[0], row[3]) for row in reader])
```

The problem is that the `extend` does not work because `reader` has already been iterated through ...

Any suggestions on how I can do this in one single list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a second iteration:

```
rows = [value for row in reader
        for value in [(row[0], row[2]), (row[0], row[3])]]
```